# Integrate repeating code in swiftUI, like inherit or something

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have some SwiftUI View which are having lots of repeating part like below:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SomeView: View {
// start of the repeating part
    @EnvironmentObject var mainViewModel: MainViewModel
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: AuthViewModel
    init(viewModel:AuthViewModel){
        self.viewModel = viewModel
    }
    
// end of the repeating part
    
    var body: some View {
      // some view
    }
}
```

In java or Kotlin I can just simply inherit a class of its type,
but I've notice that struct can't be inherit.
So what would be the alternative way to achieve this?

Comment: Generics is one solution, `struct SomeView<Content: View>: View`

Comment: Use *composition* and *aggregation* concepts instead of *inheritance*.

Answer (score -1):

Protocol and protocol extensions are the alternative of inheritance.

[https://www.hackingwithswift.com/sixty/9/4/protocol-extensions](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/view-composition)

I guess in your case, you try to handle different authentication views consider using view composition.

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/view-composition